# Creating a trigger when value is NULL use old value. Nested exception error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello and thanks for viewing this, I have a table (with names changed from real names and some other info left out, please let me know if there is any more info on the table you'd like)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`coursetwo` (
  `candidate_no` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `course_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`candidate_no`),
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

And I have an update query on a form which updates the table's course date and name for a candidate. Here is the query:

```
UPDATE coursetwo SET course_date=?, course_name=? WHERE candidate_no = ?;
```

When a user wants to go back and enter just one value, say the course_name and submit it, it sets the course date to null and not keeping the previous known input.

I am creating a trigger if a value is null then use the old value, however I am getting a nested exception error :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE coursetwo SET course_date=?, course_name=? WHERE candidate_no=?]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1442]; Can't update table 'coursetwo' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger; nested...

Here is my trigger:

```
delimiter #
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ifnull_keep_old_values# 
create trigger ifnull_keep_old_values after update on coursetwo
for each row
begin
    IF NEW.course_date IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE example
    SET course_date = OLD.course_date WHERE candidate_no = OLD.candidate_no;
    END IF;
END#
DELIMITER ;
```

Does any one know what is wrong with this and if there is another work around? I have many tables and columns to change and I would have to do this trigger around 50 times for each (very bad!) . I am not so knowledgeable on triggers so any help would be great!

Thanks for taking the time to read and help me :)

Comment: Also, keep in mind if that UPDATE inside the query worked, you would have just updated the entire table for a single row change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to preserve the current value of `course_date` when an update happens that would have set it to `NULL`.

MySQL will not let you update the same table in the trigger that fires on the same table, hence the error you are getting.

However, in your use case, all you have to do is dynamically change the value that is about to be updated in a `BEFORE` trigger.

Like :

```
delimiter #
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ifnull_keep_old_values# 
CREATE TRIGGER ifnull_keep_old_values BEFORE UPDATE ON coursetwo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.course_date IS NULL THEN SET NEW.course_date = OLD.course_date;
    END IF;
END#
DELIMITER;
```

If you want to deal with more columns on the same table, then do it within the same trigger. You just have to add additional `IF NEW.... IS NULL THEN NEW... = OLD...` clauses. If you want to implement the same logic on other tables, then you have to create a new trigger for each table.

Here is an alternative body for the trigger that avoids the use a `BEGIN/END` block. The `COALESCE` function returns its first argument (here the new course date) unless it is `NULL`, in which case the second argument (old course date) is returned.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ifnull_keep_old_values BEFORE UPDATE ON coursetwo
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.course_date = COALESCE(NEW.course_date, OLD.course_date)
;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it needs to be a *before update* trigger as well.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks for checking, updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Alternative trigger body: `... FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.course_date = COALESCE(NEW.course_date, OLD.course_date);` so you don't need a BEGIN/END block, and therefore don't need to change the `DELIMITER`.

Comment: thanks @BillKarwin, I added this alternative solution to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much everyone :) I was quite close I guess ha! That worked @GMB and thanks for saying to change to a before update too! 

My problem is that I would have to do this for 4 more columns in this table and I have 6 more tables to do the same thing. Is there a more efficient way to do it than 1 column update in one trigger? Say if any values are null , do the same thing on each column? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @GMB. Sorry I am new how do I accept an answer?